# Navigation Bar Issue

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

[image]

I'm trying to hide or remove the Navigation Bar in Xamarin **Shell** Application. but it didnt work for IOS or Android .Please Help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove navigation bar on Xamarin Forms app with Caliburn.Micro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36656895/remove-navigation-bar-on-xamarin-forms-app-with-caliburn-micro)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xamarin Forms - Getting Rid of Back Button In Nav Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24935929/xamarin-forms-getting-rid-of-back-button-in-nav-bar)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I found the answer.

**Shell.SetNavBarIsVisible(this, false);**

I added this code line to the constructor now it works.
Thank you vary much for answers.

Answer (score 0):

On the Backend so the Xaml.cs

Rather add the follow within your page constructor:

`NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);`

Comment: If you are using the shell template NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false); will not work

Answer (score 0):

just add `NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"` in the Content Page tag after adding this to you code it will look someting like this

```
<ContentPage
x:Class="YouAppPackage.View.PageName"
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">
```

or you can also set it from pages code behind

```
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
```

after adding this your code will look something like this

```
public YourPageName()
{  
   InitializeComponent();
   NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
}
```

hope this helps you